# I am trying to join 2 tables with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to join 2 tables with inner join , the second table is a big table. so when I run the query it's taking too long. Here's the sample of my query.

```
select distinct name,number,ID,count 
from Import A 
inner join Claim B 
  on B.ClaimNo between A.beginClaimNumber and A.endClaimnumber 
where cast(Receivedate as date) between ('2015-01-01') and ('2015-03-01') 
  and B.IO = 'O' 
order by ID
```

Comment: `taking too long` is not really an error.  There could be many things that are causing this, none of which relate to your query.  Start with indexes.

Comment: Remove the `CAST` and `BETWEEN` class in `WHERE` clause and try something `SARGable`, refer here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: Make sure that you have index on the `Claim  table on ClaimNo columns`.

Comment: I added cast because the Receivedate is a timestamp.

Comment: I do have multiple indexes in the claim table , do you think adding an index on the IO would be a good idea. If I remove the B.IO from the query , the query seems to be executing some results but still take longer, if I add the B.IO = 'O' then it takes forever.

Comment: can we have the sample data of both the tables ?

Comment: What happens if you do Receivedate between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-01 23:59:59' instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an index on import that covers the query using INCLUDE.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190806.aspx

Then add another on Claim on claimNo and include beingClaimNumber and endClaimNumber.

Also check the execution plan in SQL management studio, it might give you suggestions.